# Creating a Toggle Option for Start App On bootup

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, boot

So essentially I am making an application that will run in the background. Now my application has an option to start and stop the service but by default will run that service on bootup.

Is there a way to make a toggle switch kind of similar to "Start on Windows Startup" that allows the user to enable whether or not they want the service to start when the bootup their phone?

If this was my code..which starts the BG service which runs the activity:

```
public class startOnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(context,backgroundService.class);
context.startService(intent);
Log.i("Autostart", "Service Started");
}
}
```

And I have my toggle button:

```
final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    enableReceiver(Home.this);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    disableReciever(Home.this);
                }
            }
        });
```

And the two functions:

```
public void enableReceiver(Context context) {
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, startOnBoot.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                component,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public void disableReciever(Context context) {
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, startOnBoot.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                component,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

The problem is although this may enable and disable the feature; if i restart the phone it will go to default what my AndroidManifest reads which is disabled by default. So the solution isn't permanent, it resets. I dont know if this is the right approach but what would I need to do to allow a user to choose whether or not they want the auto bootup function.

Comment: First off-  use JobScheduler rather than doing your own BroadcastReceiver.  Its easier.  You could then cancel the job and restart it with a different persistant setting when they flip the switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can store value of toggle switch (true or false) in sharedprefrences. Retrieve it in receiver and  if its true, then start your service.